# HTML Align text to right of image?

Tags: html, image, email

I am looking to move the "Text" to the right of the image, when I align the image tag and use align="left" it brings all text to the right of the image but I want the caption to stay below.  I think I may be missing an addition tag to do this.  Any suggestions? This is in an email.

```html
<figure style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;">
 <img src="http://image.comm.housingpartnership.net/lib/fe9513727667017c70/m/1/Robin+Hughes.jpg" title="Robin Hughes" alt="Robin Hughes" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" mdid="ff508d18-ad83-4b37-a12c-f8249c7917dc" width="160"  height="240" style="width: 160px; height: 240px;" />
 <figcaption>Caption Here</figcaption>
</figure>
<p id="text-placeholder" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
 <font face="Arial">
  <span style="font-size: 13px;">
   Text
  </span>
 </font>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `float: left` to your `figure` tag

```html
<figure style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; float: left;">
 <img src="http://image.comm.housingpartnership.net/lib/fe9513727667017c70/m/1/Robin+Hughes.jpg" title="Robin Hughes" alt="Robin Hughes" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" mdid="ff508d18-ad83-4b37-a12c-f8249c7917dc" width="160"  height="240" style="width: 160px; height: 240px;" />
 <figcaption>Caption Here</figcaption>
</figure>
<p id="text-placeholder" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
 <font face="Arial">
  <span style="font-size: 13px; display: inline;">
   Text
  </span>
 </font>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks @BDD this worked perfectly and the best one to use for this current problem!

Comment: @c.hunter90 Be aware with this solution on smaller screens, the "Text" will break line and get pushed down under the caption/image

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css inline-block display style for this.

display:inline-block;

I also put vertical-align:top on the text field so that's aligned with the image.

```html
<figure style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; display:inline-block">
 <img src="http://image.comm.housingpartnership.net/lib/fe9513727667017c70/m/1/Robin+Hughes.jpg" title="Robin Hughes" alt="Robin Hughes" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" mdid="ff508d18-ad83-4b37-a12c-f8249c7917dc" width="160"  height="240" style="width: 160px; height: 240px;" />
 <figcaption>Caption Here</figcaption>
</figure>
<p id="text-placeholder" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; width: 200px">
 <font face="Arial">
  <span style="font-size: 13px;">
   Text long sklsdfklsfkls fsf sdfd sa Text long sklsdfklsfkls fsf sdfd saText long sklsdfklsfkls fsf sdfd saText long sklsdfklsfkls fsf sdfd saText long sklsdfklsfkls fsf sdfd saText long sklsdfklsfkls fsf sdfd saText long sklsdfklsfkls fsf sdfd sa
  </span>
 </font>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks @Bob Brinks this worked but would only allow me to add one line of text if I did more it would bring it back down to below the image

Comment: Adding a width to the elements will fix this (i've updated the snippet). You could use pixels or % for this width.

Answer (score 0):

Use `table` when making HTML mail, it is simple and easy to do layout, and has the best support.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://image.comm.housingpartnership.net/lib/fe9513727667017c70/m/1/Robin+Hughes.jpg" title="Robin Hughes" alt="Robin Hughes" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" mdid="ff508d18-ad83-4b37-a12c-f8249c7917dc" width="160"  height="240" style="width: 160px; height: 240px;" />
    </td>
    <td valign="top" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px;">
      Text
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Caption
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

see here **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/163hmt24/)**

set `display:inline-block` to the image and the text .
 and you also need to set `vertical-align:top` to the text because `display:inline-block` automatically sets `vertical-align:baseline`;

also you can incorporate this code in the html style

code added:

```
figure,#text-placeholder { 
   display:inline-block;
}

#text-placeholder {
   vertical-align:top;
}
```